# Which language is used in google maps frontend?

Tags: maps, frontend

I want to know this because I want to do something 'explorable' with just the mouse, with zoom-in and out, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Maps are served to the user as HTML+CSS+JavaScript (except Street View, which uses Adobe Flash). If you want to build upon their excellent JS libraries, check out the [Google Maps Javascript Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) - it's quite clear and includes many examples.

Also check out [these excellent tutorials](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/) - although they were written for GMaps API version 2, they can be easily modified for the current (version 3) API.