# what language does google and others use

Tags: programming-languages, web

What language/framwork does google and others like msn, yahoo, orkut, facebook, twiiter etc use. Or for the matter of fact any popular website.

I know the following

1. **Facebook** - PHP
2. **Yahoo** - PHP
3. **Gmail** - Java
4. **Twitter** - ROR and Scala
5. **Foursquare** - Scala

What about others

**EDIT:**

Google employees are officially allowed to use 4 languages Python, Java, C++, JavaScript. this does not mean they cant use other languages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Google Search** - Python (http://python.about.com/b/2006/11/17/creative-search-technology-with-python.htm)

[**Google Wave Protocol**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Wave_Federation_Protocol) - Java (http://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/ (You can check it out and study it, just 40000 rows ;) ))

**Google Wave Front-End** - Google Web Toolkit (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/examples/)

**Google Moderator Front-End** - Google Web Toolkit (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/1.6/examples/)

**Google Maps Front-End** - JavaScript ([Which language is used in google maps frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152787/which-language-is-used-in-google-maps-frontend))

**Gmail Frontend** - JavaScript (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gmail#Code_changes)

Answer (score 0):

Google really uses a a variety of different technologies/languages for their purposes.

For example Python

> "Python has been an important part of Google since the beginning, and remains so as the system grows and evolves. Today dozens of Google engineers use Python, and we're looking for more people with skills in this language." said Peter Norvig, director of search quality at Google, Inc.

(quote taken from [python.org](http://www.python.org/about/quotes/))

On [their help](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/topic.py) pages you can see the ".py" file extensions in your browsers address bar ;)
Maybe the do also use it for their search pages?

I'm sure things like their [Google's Filesystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System) is written in C or C++.

The frontends of GMail and Google Maps are (afaik) created with Java and the [Google Web Toolkit](http://code.google.com/intl/de/webtoolkit/).

In conclusion: There is no definite answer to your questions since Google really incorporates lot of different technologies for different problems...

Comment: there needed be one single language that's why i created this question

Comment: With this many product how do you think there will be one language?